# LDAP Monitoring

Tags: ldap, monitoring

I know LDAP is a Protocol but is there a way to monitor it?
I am using [WhatsUps](http://www.whatsupgold.com/) Gold monitoring and have been asked to look into LDAP monitors.

How can I set up monitoring for LDAP?

Comment: What kind of monitoring are you looking for? Security? Log file alerts?
Please provide more information on what you are specifically looking to monitor.

Answer (score -1):

There is no standard for monitoring LDAP directory services, but most of the products support getting monitoring information via LDAP itself, under the "cn=monitor" suffix.

Servers such as OpenDJ (continuation of the OpenDS project, replacement of Sun DSEE) also have support for monitoring through SNMP and JMX.

Regards,

Ludovic.

Answer (score -1):

I have been using cnmonitor (http://cnmonitor.sourceforge.net/) for some years with excellent results, although it's not perfect and there are some errors. You can see lots of statistics without almost doing anything: number of requests, searches, add, modifications, deletes, index status, replication, schema, etc. It is also compatible with many different LDAP servers (although I have only used it with 389 Directory Server).